# How to dispatch an action that changes the state of a component from its parent component?

Tags: react-redux, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a modal dialog that asks if I'm sure if I want to delete or not an item in application. I've this components:

```
const Options = item => (
    <OptionsMenu>
        <MenuItem onClick={_ => {
            console.log(`Deleting item ${JSON.stringify(item)}`)
        }}>
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete" color="accent">
                <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography>
                Eliminar
            </Typography>
        </MenuItem>
        <DeleteDialog
            item={item}
        />
    </OptionsMenu>
)
```

And my dialog component is:

```
const DeleteDialog = props => (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => {
        this.props.openDeleteDialog(this.props.item)
      }}>Delete</Button>
      <Dialog open={this.props.open} onRequestClose={this.props.cancelDeleteData}>
        <DialogTitle>{"DELETE"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Are you sure you want to delete the item: {this.props.item.name}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={this.props.cancelDeleteData} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.props.deleteData(this.props.item)} color="primary">
            Delete
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
open: state.item.delete.open,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
...deleteDispatchesForScope(scopes.ITEM, dispatch)
})
```

What I want is to dispatch the openDeleteDialog action, that sets the open state to true, from the Options component in a way that I will allow me to reuse the modal Dialog in other components.
I'm using react-redux and material-ui v1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have more reusable components, I would decouple the `DeleteDialog` from the `OptionsMenu`, and rely on a `ParentComponent` to pass down the props required for each child:

```es7
<ParentComponent>
  <OptionsMenu>
    <MenuItem onClick={this.props.openDeleteDialog}>Eliminar</MenuItem>
  </OptionsMenu>
  <DeleteDialog 
    open={this.props.isDeleteDialogOpen} 
    item={this.props.item} 
    onDelete={this.props.deleteData} 
  />
</ParentComponent>
```